# Spark Dataframe-Python

Tags: python, apache-spark

In pandas, I can successfully run the following:

```
def car(t)
    if t in df_a:
       return df_a[t]/df_b[t]
    else:
       return 0
```

But how can I do the exact same thing with spark dataframe?Many thanks!
The data is like this

```
df_a
a 20
b 40
c 60

df_b
a 80
b 50
e 100
```

The result should be 0.25 when input car(a)

Comment: What are you trying to compute?

Comment: I am using hadoop, just want to convert the code from pandas to spark

Comment: Yes but what does that function do, you should show the input and the output.

Comment: df_a contain the id, I run df_a.value_counts() before I run the code above.

Comment: Are you using Scala or Pyspark?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I am using pyspark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to `join` both dataframes, then you have to `filter` by the letter you want and `select` the operation you need.

```py
df_a = sc.parallelize([("a", 20), ("b", 40), ("c", 60)]).toDF(["key", "value"])
df_b = sc.parallelize([("a", 80), ("b", 50), ("e", 100)]).toDF(["key", "value"])

def car(c):
  return df_a.join(df_b, on=["key"]).where(df_a["key"] == c).select((df_a["value"] / df_b["value"]).alias("ratio")).head()

car("a")

# Row(ratio=0.25)
```

Comment: One more question, can the input be a dataframe? I would like to input a dataframe df_c which conatin the key and then the car() will loop through each row of the key in df_c and then the output will the ratio for each key.

Comment: You have to show me an example first. However, avoid thinking in such imperative way, spark is lazy and most of computation is done in parallel